# Admob not working?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios5, admob, ads

I made an app before and this code worked before the 5.0.1 update but it wont work on the new app. What could be the problem?

Here's the code:

```
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
// Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen. 
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height - GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)]; 
// Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID. 
bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID; 
// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking 
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy. 
bannerView_.rootViewController = self; [self.view addSubview:bannerView_]; 
// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad. 
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];}
```

Comment: The AdMob SDK has logging enabled by default. What do they say in your console?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker stopNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
      -[GADMNetworkReachabilityWrapper unscheduleFromCurrentRunLoop] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADMNetworkReachabilityWrapper.o)

Comment: "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
      -[GADMNetworkReachabilityWrapper

Comment: initWithHostname:callbackDelegate:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADMNetworkReachabilityWrapper.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
      -[GADMNetworkReachabilityWrapper scheduleInCurrentRunLoop] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADMNetworkReachabilityWrapper.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in

Comment: libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
      -[GADMNetworkReachabilityWrapper initWithHostname:callbackDelegate:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADMNetworkReachabilityWrapper.o)
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[GADWebViewDelegate webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADWebViewDelegate.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:

Comment: objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: thats what it says! the problem is im using the same exact code in another app and it works perfectly fine but in this app it doesnt work and it doesnt work in any new project either.

Answer (score 19):

Are you sure that you've linked your project binary to the following libraries in your build settings:

- AudioToolbox
- MessageUI
- SystemConfiguration
- CoreGraphics

Comment: i think that solved the problem! but i cant see the ads when it runs so idk if thats on admobs end or not. thanks!

Comment: Along with all those, I had to add `storeKit` as well. Great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to replace `MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID` with your actual publisher ID to get ads if you haven't done that already.

Also, any AdMob SDK 5.0.x release requires you to use XCode 4.2 or above.  Try updating if you don't already have 4.2.

Comment: i have xcode 4.2 and i have this code at the top:#define MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID @"a14e88b5295e0a6"